# Eclipse- gwt::how can i swith to older version of gwt (google Google Web Toolkit)?

Tags: installation, java, eclipse

I use gwt-cal and its not working for gwt 2.xx versions, I need to setup gwt 1.7.xx version instead. I already download the gwt [1.7.xx.zip](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/list?can=1&q=GWT+1.7.0&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+Size+DownloadCount) version inside Eclipse.

In 1.7.xx.zip exists files tipes: jar, war, dll - in this case I don't know which files I should use and how to install them.

My System:
Windows Vista, Eclipse 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gwt-cal works with gwt 2.0, i'm using it with the new gwt 2.1M1 release. According to the website it says that gwt-cal 0.9.0 is "for gwt version 1.7 or higher"